# Laravel email verification redirect user back to verification url after login

Tags: laravel, email, authentication

When a user registers a email verification link is sent to them that looks something like:

```
https://mysite.test/email/verify/3?expires=1574693909&hash=09ec600dfgdfgdfgc0b7c36bc775487fdgdg45312f46fc06107&signature=5581f53e9asdfasdf6f97657bc0f939a9bc368b6cd2dfgdgerg62c1711de44d
```

The odd behaviour is that the user must me logged in when he/she clicks on the email verification link, if the user is not logged in while clicking on the link they will be redirected to the login page, if they then login they will be redirected to the page that says they must verify their email cause of the `auth:verified` middleware.

What I would like is when a user who is not logged in clicks on the email verification link and gets redirected to the login page and logs in, **then** should be redirected to the email verification url again.

So is there any way to change so a user can be redirected to a special login page for a certain page? Or jusr modify the VerificationController to just allow none-authenticated users to "acitvate" their email by clicking on the link.

I was thinking to redirect the user to this login page that stores a session of the previous URL:

```
public function showRedirectLoginForm()
    {
        $previous_url = Session::get('_previous.url');
        $ref = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
        $ref = rtrim($ref, '/');
        if ($previous_url != url('login')) {
            Session::put('referrer', $ref);
            if ($previous_url == $ref) {
                Session::put('url.intended', $ref);
            }
        }

        return view('auth.login');
    }
```

Then in my logincontroller I can simply redirect the user to the previous page:

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
            if (Session::has('referrer')) {
                return redirect()->intended(Session::pull('referrer'));
            } else {
                return redirect('/account');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem before, my solution is you can delete `$this->middleware('auth');` in `_construct()` method in VerificationController to let none-authenticated user to verify from their email then in `verify()` method inside VerificationController you can modify the code like this :

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->route('id'));

    if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    if ($user->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
```

Comment: Did you set the redirect path to home?

Comment: and make sure you delete the `$this->middleware('auth');`